# Sustainable population - When to breed

Tags: real-analysis, systems-of-equations, bounded-variation

I would like advice on an approach to solving this real world problem.  I'm not certain if the solution is to solve a system of equations, or something else.  The problem is stated below with the equation systems that I derived from it.  I think I have it solved by using a table, but I was hoping for a system of equations

> If it takes a species:
>
> - 52 days from conception to become "useful" (and they remain "useful" until death),
> - 73 days from conception to reach adulthood (ability to breed/conceive again),
> - 108 days from conception until death, and
> - each generation gets exactly 1 day to breed
>
> *A)* What is the minimum number of living generations required to always have a useful population?
>
> *B)* To maintain this minimum number of generation what day in their life cycle should they breed?

In other words, if we have the following definitions for generation, $Gen_n$:

\begin{array}{ll}
c_n,  & \text{day of conception} \\
b_n, & \text{day of breeding} 
\end{array}

And we have to following functions and systems:

$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned} 
&Useful(c_n) = c_n + 52 \\ 
&Adult(c_n) = c_n + 73 \\
&Death(c_n) = c_n + 108 \\
&b_n = c_{n+2} \text{ ; breeding day is conception day} \\
&Useful(c_n) <= Death(c_{n-1}) \text{ ; Useful when prev gen dies} \\
&Useful(b_n) - Death(c_n) <= c_{n+1} \text{ ; $Gen_{n+1}$ can survive until next gen matures} \\
&b_{n+1} >= Death(c_n) \text{ ; At most 3 generations so $Gen_{n+1}$ can't breed until $Gen_{n}$ has died} \\
\end{aligned} 
\right. 
$$

Solve for $b_n$

> So part *A*'s answer is 3.
>
> But how to solve *B*?  My brute force table shows
>     $b_n$ =
>   \begin{cases}
> 0 < b_n < 18,  & \text{if $n$ is even} \\
> 0 < b_n < 21, & \text{if $n$ is odd}
> \end{cases}
>   for me {0,18} is sufficient

\begin{array}{r|r|r|r|r|r}
  Range & Useful & Conception & Death & Earliest Breed & Actual Breed \\ \hline
  - & 52 & 0 & 108 & 73 & 73 \\
0 & 108 & 17 & 125 & 90 & 108 \\
  21 & 125 & 73 & 181 & 146 & 146 \\
  18 & 181 & 108 & 216 & 181 & 181 \\
  21 & 216 & 146 & 254 & 219 & 219 \\
  18 & 254 & 181 & 289 & 254 & 254 \\
  21 & 289 & 219 & 327 & 292 & 292 \\
  18 & 327 & 254 & 362 & 327 & 327 \\
\end{array}